# Laravel MySQL Auto Increment Issue Local Vs Remote

Tags: mysql, sql, heroku, laravel

I have a Users table with an auto incrementing ID value, pretty normal stuff. However on my test server which I've just been experimenting with for the last few days the ID field is incrementing by 10, So I have User_id 1, 11, 21, 31... and it does the same for the other tables too.

My local MAMP MySQL works fine with the exact same repository. Could anyone please shed some light on why this might be happening. I'm using Sequel Pro to read my databases,

Database engine: InnoDB (on both)

My model states this;

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
```

*Many thanks*

Answer (score 0):

I think you have changed auto_increment value. You can change it by doing (in your database) :

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=1;
```